# PWM circuit that switches MOSFET with soft edges

Tags: power, pwm

I've recently bought a soldering iron from China that buzzes audibly as it heats up the tip. I'm trying to understand the reason it makes the buzzing sound and mitigate it. What I observe is that as the tip heats up, there is an audible buzzing noise coming from the handle, the control board, and the power supply.

Here’s a video showing this problem, with the audio slightly amplified: https://youtu.be/Imbg9Skw5vQ

The working principle of the iron is quite simple (and this circuit is their exact implementation):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu45Ji.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It PWMs 24V into the tip and uses a PID control loop to measure the temperature and adjust the duty cycle as needed.

The iron (Aixun T3A) is rated for 200W, so the MOSFET switches hard when very significant current (~8A) is flowing. My current suspicion is that because the switching edges are too sharp, the significant change in magnetic field causes components in the PCB and the iron handle to vibrate.

So I would like to design a circuit that takes as input a 5V PWM like this:

[image]

and outputs a 24V high current PWM with softer edges (without any significant delay):

[image]

I'm not sure where to start with this. If I simply add a 10n capacitor across R2 for example, that messes up the timing of the PWM. Thanks for any help and guidance.

Comment: You will also need to consider the additional heat that will be generated and how to get rid of it.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that operating the mosfet in its linear region will produce some heat. That's perfectly fine. I have spare heatsinks

Comment: I suspect this will solve your problems because the switching is already within the audible range. Although slowing down the rise/fall by adding some capacitors across the switching elements will tame some of the very high frequency harmonics, the fundamental (166 Hz) is still there. If fundamental is there then powerful harmonics are there as well. `as the tip heats up, there is an audible buzzing noise coming from the handle, the control board, and the power supply.` This could be the power supply as well i.e. it might be struggling to deliver the required power (192W times the duty cycle).

Comment: What frequency does it buzz at? The heat regulation frequency could be low but the power supply behind it may have the usual oscillation at the corner frequency of the output LC, usually in the 6-8 kHz region. This is notoriously common on cheap power supplies despite adding zero BOM cost to fix.

Comment: You can reduce higher harmonics this way, but likely not enough of them to reduce audibility. A microphone reading of the sound might be helpful. I assume it's an impulsive sound, but centered around what frequencies, is the question.

Comment: If all the time you spent pondering this was instead spent doing paid work at your EE profession, you could have used that money to buy a premium Metcal iron by now... I really don't get the whole "buy cheap crap from China then spend ridiculous amounts of time trying to uncrap it" philosophy. Time is money, especially if you have a job IRL where you could be paid when pondering over similar design concerns.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I’ve tried to power it from a linear bench supply, but that didn’t improve the buzzing.

Comment: @winny I’ve included a link to a video in the question that demonstrates the problem. If the power supply is oscillating, would that cause a buzzing noise in the handle? When I powered it with a bench supply, it was still buzzing.

Comment: @TimWilliams please refer to the video to see the buzzing frequency.

Comment: @Lundin I’m not an EE by trade, though I studied it in university. My day job is software engineering. So I’m not as skilled or informed. This iron had good reviews, and I liked that it could power JBC 245 tips which are known to be amazing.

Comment: @darksky That wasn't the point, my point was that you could maybe work overtime doing the software engineering you are good at, and use the money earned to buy yourself a JBC or Metcal? Instead of reverse engineering some hackjob iron from Aliexpress. I suspect it is not only the tips that make the JBC amazing, but rather the whole iron including how they implement heat sensing.

Comment: Well, I would just as well suggest a lower-tier but still professional type, like Hakko FX-888 or Weller WESD51. But this unit isn't necessarily *bad*, just noisy.

Comment: @TimWilliams Come on, why would a _solder iron_ make noise? If it was coil whine then maybe I could buy it, but this is something else apparently.

Comment: I'm used at both Metcal and Hakko irons and the former is significantly better in pretty much every single aspect. And then Hakko is a well-known brand and not just some cheap crap. You could get a Metcal iron for some $300 and it is worth every cent (I'm not affiliated with them, just a very pleased customer).

Comment: People get bizarrely obsessive about their tools sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Relevant discussion from another community: https://www.eevblog.com/forum/reviews/any-opinions-on-the-aixun-t3a/

Buzzing isn't mentioned (or audible in the video), but it might be that build quality varies, or you have a clone or whatever.

[image: Spectrogram]

Here's the spectrogram (waterfall diagram from left to right) of audio from the video.

The blue and pink confetti is just background noise that can be ignored.  Most harmonics are in red, with the 1.5k and 1.66k harmonics being most prominent.  Probably because they're resonances of the handle or something.  It's subtle, but the harmonics seem to swish around a bit, in the bracketed area, distinctive of PWM changing.

So yeah, it's fairly low harmonics (9th and 10th, and you'll still hear the rest; 20th+ would be more practical to filter electronically).

If you want purely electronic solutions, it could indeed be filtered.  The impedance is low enough that a catch diode and series inductor could be added, and maybe filter cap too.  Downside is, we need Fc << 166Hz.  Say 40Hz to avoid cutting into the control loop bandwidth too much; this needs L = \$\frac{(3\,\Omega)}{2 \pi (40 \,\textrm{Hz})}\$ = 11mH, rated for up to 8A. Which will be a fairly large iron-core inductor.  (A cap of \$\frac{1}{2 \pi (3\,\Omega) (40 \,\textrm{Hz})}\$ = 1.3mF can additionally be used.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6m9Am.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

which would look something like this.  Note the diode must be placed adjacent to the switch transistor, and the inductor probably won't fit anywhere, it'll have to be hanging out the back of the base unit or something.

Smaller values may be reasonable (evidently around 500Hz would be the maximum to still get value, given the spectrum), but mind that they may distort the response (power output vs. duty cycle), which may upset the controller as well.

Ideally, the controller would run at much higher frequency (over 20kHz is easily done), with a compact LC filter inside the base.  I have no idea if this is at all feasible to implement. You'd at least need the schematics and firmware, and a toolchain to reprogram it.

I mean, even more ideally, the thing just wouldn't buzz at all...  Whether that's shoddy construction in the handle, base or both, or poor cabling, or a poor tip (try one of those famous JBC tips you mentioned?), who knows.  Also, you might want to check wiring quality in general; with 8A peak flowing here, it would be very easy to skimp on wire size (don't forget they're fond of copper-clad aluminum or steel wire over there..!), not to mention the mains wiring and especially ground connection may be woefully inadequate (i.e., shop for a proper UL-rated unit).

Comment: Really interesting to see only the 9th harmonic is audible. I wonder if that massive LC network needs some damping?

Comment: It does. Fortunately the load is very well defined!